# A LaTeX package to display LaTeX code?

Tags: packages

Greeting, friends,

A quick question: I am contemplating creating a "notebook" with some useful snippets of LaTeX code, examples, tips and tricks. All this stuff is accumulating in process of my work and I would like to have it in one documents for my own quick reference. I would like to have it arranged in LaTeX, obviously. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone knows of a LaTeX package that can help to display LaTeX code and display it in aesthetically pleasing way, so it looks nice in resulting pdf document after compilation? Thank you!

Comment: The `tcolorbox` package has very good support for that.

Comment: Thank you, Joseph! I will look into it now.